# best way to upload files(100gb+) from freebsd server

Tags: ssh, freebsd, backup, ftp

I need to upload lots of files(100gb+) from server, currently i get ssh connection, and i'm not restricted in software i can use and run anything. Please recommend me the way to upload files to my computer.

Comment: You mean "download" files to your computer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd tar and compress before I sent over SSH - the  encryption will just slow things down if you try SCP or similar natively.

`tar cvzf - /path/to/files | ssh user@host.com -C -c blowfish "cat - > bigtarball.tgz"`

If you want smarted things like synchronising collections of files after the copy, go grab the free version of Bittorrent Sync at http://www.getsync.com - save yourself the headache of rsync, Dropbox, and all the others.

Better still, grab the older version of Bittorrent Sync at http://syncapp.bittorrent.com/1.3.109/ - none of the number of folder limitations - solid as a rock on my FreeBSD 10 Intel Atom machine.

N.

Comment: doing all in a single file is dangerous when it comes to 100GB - a connection error could corrupt the files (not all `scp` version have resume support). It should be `tar`red and compressed (e.g. as `.tar.gz` with `tar -z` option) then `split`ted into reasonably sized parts (depending on connection stability and speed - I'd say some 100-500MB would be fine).

Comment: I also agree with @Nigel Weeks. You have to `tar.gz` your files before upload. This will reduce your file size and as a result upload time. I always do this when get my database backups.
`tar cvzf dump.tar.gz *` and then use `rsync` or `scp`.

Answer (score 2):

100GB+ of data seems best fit for **private torrent**.

Here is some basic info on how to start off: [Creating a Private Torrent](http://bootstrike.com/Articles/CreateTorrent/)